# QuickOSM Queries returning triangle polygon?

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis, overpass-api

I am trying to use QuickOSM to grab some highways features for a map area in QGIS 3.6. The query runs successfully but returns a triangle polygon and a straight polyline - no highways features. Never encountered this problem before, was all fine a few days ago. I've attached 2 screenshots below. Running on Overpass API returns the same results.

Polygon

[image: Polygon]

Query

[image: Query]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a protest of OpenStreetMap against the copyright legislation of the EU, all parts of OSM are closed. Overpass Turbo is also shut down as is the map. Tomorrow it'll be fine again.

https://www.openstreetmap.de/uf/en.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Just a pain that I need it today :)

Comment: me too. xD That's how I found out. I knew about the map, but I thought the API might be working. I was wrong.

Comment: See https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/talk/2019-March/082312.html for the Overpass API announcement.